# VBA count entries in different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched almost anywhere to find an approach where I can count the number of entries in different columns, but all I can find are codes that try to identify if i.e. values from column A can be find in column B.

I want a simple code that checks if i.e. **Column A** has the same number of entries as i.e. **Column B**.

For example if *column A* has entries from **A1 to A10** and *column B* has entries from **B1 to B5** then it should be FALSE, otherwise if column B has entries from **B1 to B10**, then the result should be positive (TRUE).

I just need a start and then I can adjust the code for my needs. Any help will be must appreciated!

**Note**: The values don't have to match. The code should be only about counting the number of entries. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)=COUNTA(B:B)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- It does not matter if the values are numbers or text or *Nulls* or errors.
- For the general issue of getting a worksheet formula to execute in *VBA*, consider:

  ```
  Sub DoItInVBA()
  Dim s As String, boo As Boolean

  s = "=Counta(A:A)=Counta(B:B)"
  boo = Evaluate(s)
  MsgBox boo
  End Sub
  ```

**EDIT#1:**

You need to be careful when chaining Boolean expressions.  For example

```
Sub BooTest1()
    Dim boo As Boolean
    a = 7
    b = 7
    boo = (a = b)
    MsgBox boo
End Sub
```

will return **True**, but:

```
Sub BooTest2()
    Dim boo As Boolean
    a = 7
    b = 7
    c = 7
    boo = (a = b = c)
    MsgBox boo
End Sub
```

will return **False**, because **True** does not equal **7**!

For our task, we can use `And()`:

```
Sub DoItInVBA()
    Dim s As String, boo As Boolean

    s = "=And(Counta(A:A)=Counta(B:B),Counta(B:B)=Counta(C:C))"
    boo = Evaluate(s)
    MsgBox boo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But, I want this as a VBA code, that's why I asked cause I don't know how to write the formula under a vba code.

Comment: @alex2002  Then see Ivan's approach

Comment: I really like your approach. Is it possible for example to add one more column? i.e. s = "=Counta(A:A)=Counta(B:B)=Counta(C:C)"? I tried that in VBA but it always gives False. Thanks

Comment: @alex2002  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 2):

I would either use CountA excel formula counting number of non-empty cells or use similar Worksheetfunction in VBA. See code below

```
Function CompareAtoB() As Boolean
    CompareAtoB = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
End Function
```